# 'blocked' The page at 'X' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from

Tags: c#, html, cross-domain, episerver

How I can fix this block if everything happen inside of my domain?

[blocked] The page at 'https://example.com/secure/CMS/Edit/Default.aspx' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://example.com/en/?idkeep=True&DE_VM=4&DE_LNK=183_185790&DE_RND=536512159&id=183_185790': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

This happen in the CMS called EPiServer 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I get this project in the meddle without any other developer I will know, this server has a reverse-inverse-proxy. Than without any code the server change the protocol.

But to fix or minimize this problem I ensure all scripts are assigned with relative protocol. Removing http[s]:// and leave just //

Answer (score 10):

I was getting this problem. I removed "http:" prefix from that link.

old : iframe src="http://example.com" >

new : iframe src="[//example.com](http://example.com)" >

Now it's working perfect.
Thank you.

Comment: I think this is the best answer if you need compatibility between SSL and non-SSL servers. ie you are deploying to Heroku (SSL) and testing on a localhost (non-SSL), removing the `http[s]?:` should work for both.

Comment: Yes exactly. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 2):

You can not put insecure (http not https) content (images, stylesheets, inline frames, etc.) on a secure webpage (https).
browser will block the insecure element while loading the page.

Search where in your script (https :// example.com/secure/CMS/Edit/Default.aspx) trying to access (http :// example.com/en/?idkeep=True&DE_VM=4&DE_LNK=183_185790&DE_RND=536512159&id=183_18579) and just add 'S' after http.

in other words your page should try to access http**S**://example.com/en/ not (http:// example.com /en/)

But I know, if the requested page is not available on HTTPS, there is nothing more you can do :-S

Answer (score 0):

We resolved this problem by setting the link properties to open up in a new tab and not attempt to display the insecure page in the frame on the secure page.